# How can I store and retrieve regional language php array data (gujarati, hindi, punjabi) to mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Right now I am able to store string of regional language in mysql database. But I want to store array and json encode to mysql database and want to retrieve same thing.

Right now this kind of string is inserted in the database instead of regional language.

```
["u0ab9u0ac7u0ab2u0acb u0a95u0ac7u0aae u0a9au0acb u0aaeu0abeu0a9cu0aae ?","u0ab9u0ac7u0ab2u0acb u0a95u0ac7u0aae u0a9au0acb u0aaeu0abeu0a9cu0aae ?"]
```

Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for this after a long research.

I have used JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE for this.

```
$multi_language_array = array('હેલો કેમ ચો માજમ ?', 'कैसे हो ?', 'How are you?', );

$encoded_array = json_encode($multi_language_array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

After doing so I have stored the json_encoded array string in database. And it worked.

Also on retrieve it works fine.

```
print_r(json_decode($encoded_string_from_database));

//And the output is
Array ( [0] => હેલો કેમ ચો માજમ ? [1] => कैसे हो ? [2] => How are you? )
```